# Android having problem to get contact number while incoming call

Tags: android

I am trying to set templates for my each call events, i.e. missed call, incoming call ended and outgoing call ended

I referred some code on the internet and came up with this. Now I am receiving outgoing call's contact number but there is problem on incoming call contact number. I am receiving no value.

What I am doing wrong in this code? Please help me out

> AndroidMenifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
<receiver android:name=".CallReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

PhoneStateReceiver.java :

```
public abstract class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
private static Date callStartTime;
private static boolean isIncoming;
private static String savedNumber;
protected Context savedContext;


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

    if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")){
        //number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        //Toast.makeText(context,number,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }else{
        //number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        //Toast.makeText(context,number,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }



    //We listen to two intents.  The new outgoing call only tells us of an outgoing call.  We use it to get the number.
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
        savedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");

    }else{
        String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        //String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

        int state = 0;

        if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
            //number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        }
        else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
            //number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        }
        else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
            //number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        }
        onCallStateChanged(context, state, number);
    }
}

//Derived classes should override these to respond to specific events of interest
protected void onIncomingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start){}
protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start){}
protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end){}
protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end){}
protected void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number, Date start){}

//Deals with actual events

//Incoming call-  goes from IDLE to RINGING when it rings, to OFFHOOK when it's answered, to IDLE when its hung up
//Outgoing call-  goes from IDLE to OFFHOOK when it dials out, to IDLE when hung up
public void onCallStateChanged(Context context, int state, String number) {
    if(lastState == state){
        //No change, debounce extras
        return;
    }
    switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            isIncoming = true;
            callStartTime = new Date();
            savedNumber = number;
            onIncomingCallStarted(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            //Transition of ringing->offhook are pickups of incoming calls.  Nothing done on them
            if(lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                isIncoming = false;
                callStartTime = new Date();
                onOutgoingCallStarted(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
            }
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            //Went to idle-  this is the end of a call.  What type depends on previous state(s)
            if(lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                //Ring but no pickup-  a miss
                onMissedCall(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
            }
            else if(isIncoming){
                onIncomingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
            }
            else{
                onOutgoingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
            }
            break;
    }
    lastState = state;
    }
}
```

CallReceiver.java

```
public class CallReceiver extends PhoneStateReceiver {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;



    @Override
    protected void onIncomingCallStarted(Context context, String number, Date start) {

        //openDialog(context, number);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context context, String number, Date start) {
        //openDialog(context, number);
        //sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("user_sms_pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        //SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        //Toast.makeText(context,number + " "+sharedPreferences.getString("outgoingCall", " "),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        //smsManager.sendTextMessage(number,null,sharedPreferences.getString("outgoingCall", " "),null,null);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context context, String number, Date start, Date end) {
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("user_sms_pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        openDialog(context, number);
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(number,null,sharedPreferences.getString("incomingCall", " "),null,null);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context context, String number, Date start, Date end) {
        openDialog(context, number);
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("user_sms_pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(number,null,sharedPreferences.getString("outgoingCall", " "),null,null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMissedCall(Context context, String number, Date start) {
        openDialog(context, number);
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("user_sms_pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        Toast.makeText(context,number,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(number,null,sharedPreferences.getString("missedCall", ""),null,null);
    }

    private void openDialog(Context context, String number) {

        Intent i = new Intent(context, PhoneIncomingActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        i.putExtra("Number",number);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**`android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS`** is deprecated and this will also belongs to `CallLog` permission group which is restricted in API 28 by Google.

So, you don't get no in API 28 and onward.

Comment: so Is there any way where I can get Incoming call number?

Comment: No Way if not default. Check this out: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303?hl=en